# System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine being stepped over

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 in an ASP.NET MVC/C# project.

I am outputting to the output window using

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine
```

but for some reason VS has stopped running this line. I am executing in Debug mode. If I step through the code the debugger will jump over this line.

Is this controlled by a setting. I have searched the web but nothing obvious jump out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to project settings and see if there is check mark in front of `Define DEBUG constant`. Most likely that it's not there, although it should be by default.

If `DEBUG` constant is not defined - the method you are referring to is removed by compiler. That's why your debugger acts like code is not there.

Comment: yep - it is checked. I should say this has been working perfectly since I have created the project so obviously something has changed. The problem is I have no idea what...

Comment: @wbm Source control with regular commits would assist you in seeing what has been changed.

Comment: @wbm just to make sure put `#define DEBUG` in the beginning of the file where you use Diagnostics and rebuild.

Comment: I'm certainly doing that. Going over the latest changesets since I know it to have been working only shows changes to my code files, no property setting etc. The only config like change is a line I added to web.config. <globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU"/>, but don;t think this would impact it, or would it

Comment: Anri - that line has worked. Are you able to give me any further insight into what this command controls, can this be configured in the IDE or elsewhere. Still confused as to why this behaviour would have just changed

Comment: @wbm is the code file in web project, the same one you are debugging, or in dll?

Comment: it is in the project. BTW, thanks for the quick fix. It works a treat.

Comment: @wbm you want to look into conditional compilation symbols to understand that. Long story short, there is 2 ways (to my knowledge) to define this symbols. 1. using `#define` directive; 2. using compiler command. As it says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debug(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @wbm you can use those symbols to include/exclude code on compilation stage. To do it, use #ifdef directive.

Comment: @wbm Now regarding your problem, that check mark controls whether or not this DEBUG symbol will be defined as compiler parameter. If it's not working, i would suggest the following. 1. Uncheck it, save, check again, save. 2. Make sure that you are editing correct configuration. When project preferences are open, you can switch between configurations (Debug, Release) in there. 3. Try to open project file as text and look for "DEBUG", see if it's there, compare with another, freshly created project.